# How can I properly use COUNTIFS with a defined named range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that counts the number of contact attempts for each month. The problem I am facing is that the formula only goes up to row 2000. How can I rewrite my formula to adjust with newly added rows? Formula I am using

`=COUNTIFS(clientmenu!M8:HD2000,">="&$O$25,clientmenu!M8:HD2000,"<="&$O$26)`

[Link to Workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vqft18br7fznxfw/sampleWB.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: The workbook you linked does not look like the one you are referring to in your question. In any case, I'd probably just take the whole column `M:HD`.

Comment: @Jerry apologies for the incorrect link, I have updated my post with the correct one

Comment: All right, and can you not use `M:HD` instead of `M8:HD2000`?

Comment: Why not you are using `20000` instead of `2000`?

Comment: @Jerry I could use that but I am not sure if that would cause the formula to calculate cells that don't have data in them. I'm afraid it would cause calculation / performance issues

Comment: Well you can try and see if it does or not. I'm not sure why you are asking that. Did the formula ever calculate cells that don't have data in them before you got to 2000 rows? As for the second one, you will always get decline in performance the more things there are to process, that's how things are.

Comment: Since Excel 2007 it adjusts itself to only see the used range when you reference a whole column.  `=COUNTIFS(clientmenu!M:HD,">="&$O$25,clientmenu!M:HD,"<="&$O$26)` should be faster.  Untested though.